# nginx rewrite for static content

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

I am serving static html with nginx.
I'd like mydomain.com to show index.html in the root folder. For links of the form `/pages/page` I want them to go to the root directory and pull up `page.html` from the pages folder.

Here's what I came up with:

```
location / {
  root /var/www/public_html;
  index  index.html;
  try_files $uri $uri.html http://mysite.com;
}
```

However, I get a 404 when I  go to my site. It does render index.html if I use `try_files /index.html $uri $uri.html http://mysite.com;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to use `try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html http://mysite.com;`. I thought the index directive was enough..